# Interchange two forked process with semaphores

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, fork, semaphore

I am trying to write a program that interchanges two forked children processes with semaphores but I am not sure how to do that. For example, I have child1 and child2 and both of them call the same function. I want them to go through the function once at a time, if I run it 10 times, I want it to look like
child1
child2
child1
child2
child1
child2
child1
child2
child1
child2. I am also using shared memory that stores the semaphores that I have.

Comment: What do you have so far? You seem to have the basic ideas there: children talk to each other with a semaphore, and the semaphore has to live in shared memory so they're both using the same semaphore.

Comment: I initialize the semaphore to 1, then in the beginning of the function, I wait for the semaphore and after I am done I call sem_post on that semaphore. However that logic for some reason runs child1 all the time. So I need help in figuring out the logic for creating a program the will interchange the two children created by fork.

Comment: Stating what you've tried and how it doesn't work is helpful. It sounds like you just made a mutual exclusion lock, which would just keep both from using it at the same time. You need more state information somewhere, like which one went last.

Answer (score 1):

Use 2 Semaphore, first initialised with one and the other to 0.
**Process child1 :**

```
consume by 1 semaphore 1
do action
increase by 1 semaphore 2
```

**Process child2 :**

```
consume by 1 semaphore 2
do action
increase by 1 semaphore 1
```